# How to represent NULL character in CSV data set with PHPUnit database extension

Tags: php, postgresql, phpunit

I'm trying to use PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase to validate a few database operations in application code.

I've produced a CSV dump that looks like this (where the empty records are postgres null characters):

```
id,one,two,three
1, a,b,c
2, d,e,f
3,,,
4,g,,h
```

and I'm trying to load the dataset in as follows:

```
$dataSet = new PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_CsvDataSet();
$dataSet->addTable('test',dirname(__FILE__)."/tables/test.csv");
```

I get the following:

```
PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_Operation_Exception: COMPOSITE[INSERT] operation failed on query:

INSERT INTO example ("id", "one", "two", "three") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);

[SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp:""]

I've tried multiple characters in place of an empty string, including NULL & "\0".
```

I'm considering attempting to override the default methods to substitue a PHP null value in place of these values. Before I go that route, is there any other solution?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a replacement described in the PHPUnit documentation, but the empty values must be replaced by other like as *##NULL##*:

```
 $dataset = new \PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_CsvDataSet();
 $dataset->addTable('myTable', __DIR__.'/path/myTable.csv');

 $replacementDs = new \PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_ReplacementDataSet($dataset);
 $replacementDs->addFullReplacement('##NULL##', null);

 return $replacementDs;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the PHPUnit documentation:

> While this is very convenient for editing with Excel or OpenOffice,
>   you cannot specify NULL values with the CSV dataset. An empty column
>   will lead to the database default empty value being inserted into the
>   column.

Also in PHPUnit documentation:

> ```
> How to handle NULL with Flat XML / CSV Datasets?
> Do not do this. Instead, you should use either the XML or the YAML DataSets.
> ```